# How to center a list inside a div vertically?

Tags: html, css

I want to center the list inside the top-menu div.

I don't know where the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Joshua Brown</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .top-menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: #3f3535;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 42px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #2991d9;
      padding-left: 100px;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      color: #FFF;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-style: 1px #6f6767 solid;
      flex: auto;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      border-right: 1px #6f6767 solid;
    }
    
    li:first-child {
      border-style: none;
    }
    
    ul {
      display: flex;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .li {
      padding-left: 50%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-menu">
    <p>JOSHUA BROWN</p>
    <div class="li">
      <ul>
        <li>contact</li>
        <li>news</li>
        <li>concerts</li>
        <li>videos</li>
        <li>photos</li>
        <li>bio</li>
        <li>home</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've given your `.li` element  `padding-left: 50%`, which will **offset** it by 50%, not **center** it. That is to say, the left-hand edge will be exactly in the middle. It's actually **already** centered; this padding is just throwing you off. However, you may also want to look into restricting it with a `max-width` at certain breakpoints, so that it doesn't take up the full width of the row.

You also given your heading `<p>` tag a `padding-left` of `100px`, which won't work for mobile devices.... and it's a rather generic selector. I recommend removing your `<p>` padding then changing your `<p>` to a `<h1>`. To center your heading, you just need `text-align: center` on your `.top-menu`.

Finally, you've given your `<ul>` elements `display: flex`, but your `<li>` elements `display: inline-block`. The `<li>` items should be changed to `inline-flex`, and given `justify-content: center` to center them horizontally.

I've fixed all of this up, which can be seen in the following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Joshua Brown</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .top-menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: #3f3535;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 42px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #2991d9;
      /*
      padding-left: 100px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      */
    }
    
    li {
      /*display: inline-block;*/
      display: inline-flex;
      justify-content: center;
      float: right;
      color: #FFF;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-style: 1px #6f6767 solid;
      flex: auto;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      border-right: 1px #6f6767 solid;
    }
    
    li:first-child {
      border-style: none;
    }
    
    ul {
      display: flex;
      /*margin-bottom: 0;*/
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .li {
      /*padding-left: 50%*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-menu">
    <h1>JOSHUA BROWN</h1>
    <div class="li">
      <ul>
        <li>contact</li>
        <li>news</li>
        <li>concerts</li>
        <li>videos</li>
        <li>photos</li>
        <li>bio</li>
        <li>home</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use a known name such as 'li' for a class name. The solution is to just use text-align:center and remove the li class; Here is a snippet.

```css
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .top-menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: #3f3535;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 42px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #2991d9;
      padding-left: 100px;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      color: #FFF;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-style: 1px #6f6767 solid;
      flex: auto;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      border-right: 1px #6f6767 solid;
    }
    
    li:first-child {
      border-style: none;
    }
    
    ul {
      display: flex;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      text-align:center;
    }
    
    .li {
      padding-left: 50%
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Joshua Brown</title>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-menu">
    <p>JOSHUA BROWN</p>
    
      <ul>
        <li>contact</li>
        <li>news</li>
        <li>concerts</li>
        <li>videos</li>
        <li>photos</li>
        <li>bio</li>
        <li>home</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in the stylesheet:

```
.li{ padding-left: 50% }
```

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcps6mgn/6/)